# Starting debug without XDEBUG_SESSION_START at the of query

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I created basic PHP Web Application Launch configuration in PHPStrom, that uses `Xdebug`. However after hitting run, query parameter `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` is added to the end of URL, and because of the nature of my application this causes some errors inside the app. So, is there a way to stop adding that parameter at the end of URL, or maybe adding that parameter as the first query parameter in URL ?

Comment: No idea about PhpStorm but you can normally install a browser extension to start debugging from the browser (rather than the IDE). That way there's no need to use GET parameters.

Comment: Sure -- either invoke debug from outside when necessary (via bookmarklet/browser extension -- will use COOKIE instead of GET parameter -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm ) or configure xdebug to attempt to debug every single request: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact behavior of your IDE (PHPStrom), but in my experience, after you hit run and launch a browser with the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` addition to the url, you can just change the url in the browser and remove the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` part. The debugger will still be active and breakpoints will hit.

Comment: That's true, but I was looking for a solution where I wouldn't do that, because I'm lazy :)

Comment: Well, what I haven't tried is removing the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` addition completely. In my IDE (NetBeans) this is possible in the options->debugger. Surely this is possible in PHPStrom as well. But I don't know if doing this will still have the debugger ready to catch breakpoints. You'll have to find out yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found this option in PHPStorm debug settings, I guess  I'll have to live with that, thank you anyway.

Comment: PhpStorm has "Run" and "Debug" actions available. If OP wants to initiate debug session from within an IDE, then such "flag" has to be passed somehow, right? And GET/POST parameter is the most obvious (and only available) option (otherwise you have to use "Run" instead of "Debug" initiate it from outside, which gives you more control but requires extra moves).

Comment: The manual shows where to find the Xdebug settings: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html . Look under **Integrating XDebug with PhpStorm**. I'm not sure you will find it though, as I don't use PHPStrom

Comment: @Zed you never said if you could find it in the options.

Answer (score 2):

I tried. And it's possible.

You can use the browser extensions:

- Xdebug Helper for Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/
- Xdebug Helper for Chrome
  https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc.
- XDebugToggle for Safari
  https://github.com/kampfq/SafariXDebugToggle

---

Or by using the settings in the `php.ini` file.
Add the `xdebug.remote_enable=true` and `xdebug.remote_autostart=true` into your `php.ini` and restart your web server.

Something like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```